# ¿Cómo puedo refactorizar esta clase en Java?

Tags: java, eclipse, java-8, java-11

Necesito un poco de ayuda, ya que estas cosas siempre me han costado un poco.

Estoy trabajando en una clase en Java, esa clase tiene varios métodos y uno de estos es muy largo, por lo que lo he dividido en varios, ya que mucho de este código eran sentencias if-else que se podían separar en pequeños métodos.

Por poner un ejemplo ficticio, este sería la clase:

```
public class clasePrincipal() {

   @Autowired
   private Atributo1 atributo1;

   @Autowired
   private Atributo2 atributo2;

   @Autowired
   private ClaseAuxiliar auxiliar;

   public ObjetoConInformacion obtenerAlgunaInformacion(String texto) {
      ObjetoConInformacion objeto = new ObjetoConInformacion ();

      ObjetoCondicional1 condicional1 = auxiliar.getCondicional1();
      if(condicional1 != null){
         objeto.setValor1(condicional1.getAlgunValor());
      }

      ObjetoCondicional2 condicional2 = auxiliar.getCondicional2();
      if(condicional2 != null){
         objeto.setValor2(condicional2.getAlgunValor());
      }

      ObjetoCondicional3 condicional3 = auxiliar.getCondicional3();
      if(condicional3 != null){
         objeto.setValor3(condicional3.getAlgunValor());
      }

      ObjetoCondicional4 condicional4 = auxiliar.getCondicional4();
      if(condicional4 != null){
         objeto.setValor4(condicional4.getAlgunValor());
      }

      return objeto;
   }

}
```

En este caso le he puesto 4 condicionales, pero en el original existen bastantes más. Lo que he hecho es dividir esas condicionales en pequeños métodos para que quede más limpio de esta forma:

```
public class clasePrincipal() {

   @Autowired
   private Atributo1 atributo1;

   @Autowired
   private Atributo2 atributo2;

   @Autowired
   private ClaseAuxiliar auxiliar;

   public ObjetoConInformacion obtenerAlgunaInformacion(String texto) {
      ObjetoConInformacion objeto = new ObjetoConInformacion ();

      setCondicional1(objeto);
      setCondicional2(objeto);
      setCondicional3(objeto);
      setCondicional4(objeto);
      
      return objeto;
   }
   
    private void setCondicional1(ObjetoConInformacion objeto) {
        ObjetoCondicional1 condicional1 = auxiliar.getCondicional1();
        if(condicional1 != null){
            objeto.setValor1(condicional1.getAlgunValor());
        }
    }
    
    private void setCondicional2(ObjetoConInformacion objeto) {
        ObjetoCondicional2 condicional2 = auxiliar.getCondicional2();
        if(condicional2 != null){
            objeto.setValor2(condicional2.getAlgunValor());
        }
    }
    
    private void setCondicional3(ObjetoConInformacion objeto) {
        ObjetoCondicional3 condicional3 = auxiliar.getCondicional3();
        if(condicional3 != null){
            objeto.setValor3(condicional3.getAlgunValor());
        }
    }
    
    private void setCondicional4(ObjetoConInformacion objeto) {
        ObjetoCondicional4 condicional4 = auxiliar.getCondicional4();
        if(condicional4 != null){
            objeto.setValor4(condicional4.getAlgunValor());
        }
    }

}
```

Lo que sucede es que tal cual lo muestro en el segundo código, tras llamar al método `obtenerAlgunaInformacion`, el objeto me lo devuelve vacío, porque a los nuevos métodos le paso el objeto original, pero el valor se cambia dentro sin alterar el objeto original.

Neceisto pasarle el objeto original a esos métodos refactorizados y que los cambios que se hagan dentro de cada uno de ellos, se vea reflejado en el objeto principal.

Comment: Hola. ¿Has pensado en asociar tus condicionales en otro tipo de objeto, por ejemplo un `HashMap`? Es decir, en el `HashMap` tú puedes guardar pares clave:valor del tipo: `clave1:valor1, clave2:valor2, claveN:valorN`  luego, de forma dinámica, obtienes qué clave sea y obtienes el valor de esa clave. Si hay posibles casos de que sea una clave no existente, asignarías el valor por defecto para esos casos. Así no tienes que hacer `N` if ... then sino obtener la clave o las claves y sus valores sin más.

Comment: el codigo tal como lo tienes no compila, asegurate de poner un [mcve]

Comment: Concuerdo con @A.Cedano, un Map es una muy buena solución